# MySQL error on DELETE

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I try to delete a row from my table, but when I try I get an error : `#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

My query is : `DELETE FROM Posts WHERE idPosts = 6;`

I don't understand why I can't delete the post (the post with idPosts = 6 exists)

I have a trigger on the table too :

```
CREATE TRIGGER post_delete_update_lastPost_topic after delete on Posts for each row
BEGIN
  UPDATE Topics SET lastPost = (SELECT *
                                FROM Posts
                                WHERE idTopic = old.idTopic
                                ORDER BY datePosts DESC
                                LIMIT 1)
  WHERE idTopics = old.idTopic;
END $$
```

Comment: just a thought.. do you have any trigger or any constraint for cascade delete in the table `Posts`?

Comment: I add the trigger, add I have cascade constraint in the table too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your trigger you are doing a `SELECT *` whereas you should just select the column corresponding to lastPost. I suppose this is something like `SELECT postId`

Comment: Also, correct me if I'm wrong, but the trigger is set to `after`, so wouldn't `old.idTopic` be a problem? I'm actually asking...

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe: Both `OLD` and `NEW` can be used in `before` and `after` triggers (provided that they are available for that action at all).

Comment: Thanks @eggyal, I didn't know, so I thought of asking

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE Topics SET lastPost = (**SELECT ***
                                FROM Posts
                                WHERE idTopic = old.idTopic
                                ORDER BY datePosts DESC
                                LIMIT 1)
  WHERE idTopics = old.idTopic;

The SELECT * is returning several columns, try SELECT ID

Comment: You probably meant `SELECT idTopic`

Comment: I think his lastPost is a date, anyways the select should return 1 column only